# <interceptor-ref name=" "> is not Working While Using Custom Authentication Intercepter for Session

Tags: java, session, struts2

i want to Implement **Session** in My **Struts2 Application**.I am Using a Custom Intercepter class **AuthenticationIntercepter**,There i am checking Session is null or not,So Before Calling each Action, I am Passing **Reference of Intercepter** in **struts.xml** File..But **Intercepter Refrence** is not Working..this is my **struts.xml** File,please help me out...Thanx in Advance:

```
<interceptors>
            <interceptor name="authenticationInterceptor"
                class="interceptor.AuthenticationInterceptor"></interceptor>
            <interceptor-stack name="secureStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="authenticationInterceptor"></interceptor-ref>
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>


<global-results>

<result name="login" type="redirect">/Login.jsp</result>

</global-results>


<action name="loginform" class="login.LoginAction" method="execute">

   <interceptor-ref name="secureStack"/>

   <result name="success" type="redirectAction">/index1.jsp</result> 

 </action>
```

**AutenticationIntercepter class:**

```
    public class AuthenticationIntercepter implements Interceptor
    {


     private static final long serialVersionUID = 5283017925296746927L;

     @Override
     public void destroy() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     }

     @Override
     public void init() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     }

     @Override
     public String intercept(ActionInvocation actionInvocation) throws Exception 
     {
     Map<String,Object> session=actionInvocation.getInvocationContext().getSession();
    LoginBean user=(LoginBean)session.get("user");
    System.out.println("inside  intercepter clas.."+user);
    System.out.println("inside  intercepter clas.."+user.getUserName());



    if(user==null)
     {
      return ActionSupport.LOGIN;

     }
     return actionInvocation.invoke();
      }



    }
```

Comment: How *Intercepter Refrence is not Working*?

Comment: Your config looks good. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: hi Roman C..means after logout if am  trying to acess link of module of application..then it should not allow me to go there directly before login..bt its allowing now..means before going to action result it should check my itercepter class..wheter session is null or not..

Comment: hi Aleksandr M i am passing intercepter ref in the action tag,so before sucess it should check session value in intercepter class..there i am checking session status..if its null the i am redirecting it to login page..bt its not working before calling result page its not checking session in intercepter class.

Comment: Post your `AuthenticationInterceptor` class. BTW use `@` (e.g. @SuryaRawat) to mention somebody in comments, then they will be notified.

Comment: @Aleksandr M i have just posted my AuthenticationIntercepter class.

Comment: So what is not working? Does it call `intercept` method?

Comment: @Aleksandr M no it does not call intercept method.That is problem..its not going inside AuthenticationIntercepter class

Comment: Make sure that your interceptor is in `interceptor` package and it is compiled and deployed to server correctly. Check logs for errors.

Comment: @Aleksandr M i am getting an error  "java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error" before generating result page server is printing msg with this Exception on console.

Comment: got the solution..i was having some problem with intercepter-stack-name,when i changed it..it worked..

Answer (score 0):

The pseudo-logging that you are doing in your interceptor class may cause a problem because you are referencing the "user" variable before checking whether or not it is null. This will cause a NullPointerException to be thrown.

As to your specific problem, I would suggest checking that your "logout" mechanism is working properly. Based on the symptoms you describe, I would guess that the "user" variable is not being properly cleared from the session when the user logs out.

Comment: thanx for reply..but before logout when session is alive, then before every action it should go and check user inside intercepter class,whether its null or not,its not going inside my intercepter class.

Comment: got the solution..i was having some problem with intercepter-stack-name,when i changed it..it worked..